# Why does my UITableView not perform show segue, only presents modally

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, segue

Hi all I've been having a issue with my app in that all segues from a UITableView only present with 'present modally' (up from the bottom) rather than show (reveal from the right)

The relevant VC methods are

```
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 14
}


override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {


    if segue.identifier == "selectionSegue" {

    let tabController = segue.destinationViewController as UITabBarController

        if let newController = tabController.viewControllers![0] as? SelectedItemViewController {
            if let row = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()?.row{
                newController.selectedItem = pList[row]
            }
         }
    }
}


func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    itemViewItem = testList[indexPath.row%testList.count]
// where testList is a preconfigured string array of five items
    tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)

}
```

in the storyboard:

The TableView is a subview of a view controller that has a searchBar and a tableView controller. the TableVC has a single prototype cell that has a segue (show) formed by dragging from inside the cell to the destination VC. The viewController is configured as the tableViewDataSource and Delegate and also has an IBOutlet for the tableView childView.

Each row shows up fine and the tableView presents as expected (the cellForRow.. and all other methods are working as expected) however the destination view controller (a view controller in the first tab of a tab bar view controller) always arrives from the bottom.

It is not an issue with having a tabBarVC as the destination VC because the same issue arises even when i use a generic VC as the destination.

Help me figure out why I'm unable to present via 'Show'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ViewController has to be in a `UINavigationController` for it to work as a push.  To do this, select your ViewController with the TableView and select **Editor->Embed In->Navigation Controller** from the menu at the top.

As you noted, the `UITabViewController` isn't your issue, **but** you shouldn't segue to a `UITabBarController`.  They are intended to be the root viewController of your application.  The proper way to combine `UINavigationController`s and `UITabController`s is for the `UITabBarController` to be at the root, and then each tab has its own `UINavigationController`.

Comment: Amazing thanks so much, i knew it would be something simple. I don't have the chops to uprate too but thanks all the same. Additionally now that I've embedded the VCs i get a 'double segue' but ending up at the same VC, any idea why?

Comment: Describe what a double segue looks like.

Comment: Ive sorted it, it was a segue to the destination VC followed immediately by another segue from the destination VC to itself (the same Destination VC) both as show segues.

What was happening was that the button used to trigger the segue still had the performSegueWithIdentifier method as its IBAction but had the segue dragged directly from its UIButton icon to the destination vc, so when it was pressed, it performed the segue, then called 'performSegueWithIdentifier..